# Draw a frame in Spritekit

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, crop

I want to draw a frame like in the picture below, where the white part inside the circle is clear(transparent) so that i can see the scene in the background, and the gray part is non-transparent.
I've looked into the `CropNodes` but I didn't find an answer. Everything should be added to the `SKView`at the end.

[image]

Comment: If the grey part is invisible you would see what's behind it?!

Comment: oh I wanted to say that it is non-transparent and the white part is transparent.

Comment: You do mention SKCropNode, please add the code for what you have tried till now,

Answer (score 0):

```
this method works you can filter it more i am using shape node you can your texture shape node having some memory leaks in sprite kit

   #import "milkhuntMyScene.h"

   @implementation milkhuntMyScene

   -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
       if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        [self maskMe];

      }
     return self;
   }
   -(void)maskMe
   {
       //replace tomask to 1 pixel background and 778 width or acc to ur game
       // SKSpriteNode *whiteArea = [SKSpriteNode   spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"pixel1.png"];
    //[self addChild: whiteArea];
    //whiteArea.xScale=1024;

    SKSpriteNode *toMask = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] size:     CGSizeMake(2024, 778*2)];
    SKSpriteNode *mask = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"maskarea.png"];
    mask.position=CGPointMake(400, 300);
    //
    CGRect circle = CGRectMake(0, 0,mask.frame.size.width,mask.frame.size.height);
    SKShapeNode *shapeNode = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
    shapeNode.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circle].CGPath;
    shapeNode.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor;
    shapeNode.strokeColor = [SKColor blueColor];
    shapeNode.lineWidth=20;
    shapeNode.position=CGPointMake(mask.position.x/2, 100);
    [self addChild:shapeNode];

    //
    SKCropNode *cropNode = [SKCropNode node];
    [cropNode addChild: toMask];
    [cropNode setMaskNode: mask];
    [self addChild: cropNode];


   }
   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

   }

   -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
   }

   @end
```